# Using existing Office365 Active Directory with existing Azure account

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

We have a Office365 account that uses Azure Active Directory for our company e-mail accounts. We have a totally separate (different login) Microsoft Azure account that we have been using without touching Azure Active Directory within.

We are looking to implement Azure Active Directory within our apps, and would like to use our existing O365 Active Directory since it already has all the users created. Is there any way for us to somehow link our Azure account to the O365 account so we can use that active directory in our Azure account?

I have found some examples, but they all seem to use the premise that you are logging into both Azure and O365 with the same credentials. That is not how ours is setup unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a article that got me pointed pointed in the right direction and I was able to get this done:

[How to associate or add an Azure subscription to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory)

Ultimately I needed to have one Microsoft account that had sufficient permissions on both Active Directory tenants. It was tricky because both accounts were different Microsoft accounts using the same e-mail address, and either directory would not let me add another account with a duplicate e-mail address. I used a separate Microsoft account and added it as a AD guest on both directories. Once that was done, I was able to login with the new account with access to both directories and pick which directory I wanted to use within my Azure account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in combining the two (usually keeping O365 identities and making that AAD the default for your Azure subscription), you can contact Microsoft directly and they will be able to manually pair the two. As of 6 months ago (last time I did this) there was no way to do this yourself without assistance from MS.

You can open tickets through the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) or the [Office 365 web site](https://portal.office.com/Support/ContactUs.aspx).